# June 2023 Security Bulletin: Missing bug descriptions and repo tag

Tags: android-source

until the May 2023 security bulletin, Google used to provide a tag in AOSP repo (e.g. v67 für May 2023). They also provided links to all bugs on the bulletin page.
For the June 2023 bulletin, there is no tag available yet and two descriptions/links are missing (CVE-2023-21115 / CVE-2023-21121).

Any idea how to convince Google to provide the missing info?

Thanks a lot in advance.